# How to set style only for elements which has specified multiple class?

Tags: html, css

I have three `span` elements:

```
<span "id="span1" class="class1"> span 1 </span>
<span "id="span2" class="class2"> span 2 </span>
<span "id="span3" class="class1 class2"> span 3 </span>
```

I want to set the style for the element that has both `class1` and `class2`. So, while the first and third spans share `class1` and the second and third spans share `class2`, I would only like for the third one to be styled according to its classes.

Comment: In a CSS rule, if you specify multiple classes, IDs or tags with no intervening space, then they must all exist on the same object before the CSS rule matches.  This explains why the answers below work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
.class1.class2 {
    color: yellow;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/purmou/WDDsf/).

Comment: No problem, and great quick answer. +1.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
.class1.class2 {
    color: yellow;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
.class1.class2 {
    color: yellow
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You would setup your css as follows

give each the same class so that you can format all elements use id for custom

```
<style>
.class1 {
 color:green;
}
#span3 {
 color:yellow;
}
</style>

<span "id="span1" class="class1"> span 1 </span>
<span "id="span2" class="class1"> span 2 </span>
<span "id="span3" class="class1"> span 3 </span>
```

the id css will overwrite the css for the class giving you unique control over each element

Comment: well, yes. That's should be the best practice.